Different versions of additive chernoff
The additive Chernoff Bound says for $X_i \in \{0,1\}$ that satisfies $\mathbb{E}[X_i] = p,$
$$
\mathbb P\left(\sum\limits_{i}^nX_i \geq np+n\epsilon \right) \leq \exp\left(-\frac{(n\epsilon)^2}{2(np+\frac{n\epsilon}{3})}\right) .$$
This inequality given by my teacher.
I don't understand what kind of additive chernoff? I don't see anywhere in Wikipedia.
I know only this,
The additive version says that
$$
\mathbb P\left(\sum\limits_{i}^nX_i \geq np+n\epsilon \right) \leq e^{-2n\epsilon^2} .
$$
Anybody help me how to get my advisor chernoff version.

One thing I notice that it looks like Bernstein's inequality, but there's no $np$ term.

Cross-posted: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/647860/2921, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4921645/14578, https://mathoverflow.net/q/471895/37212.  Please do not post the same question on multiple sites.

Yeah, it's a bit surprising that your teacher referred to that inequality as the Chernoff bound, since it is normally known as (one of) Bernstein's inequality(ies), which I quote from wikipedia :

Let $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ be independent random variables. Suppose that $|X_i|\le M$ almost surely for all $i$. Then, for all positive $t$,
$$
{\displaystyle \mathbb {P} \left(\sum _{i=1}^{n}X_{i}\geq t\right)\leq \exp \left(-{\frac {{\tfrac {1}{2}}t^{2}}{\sum _{i=1}^{n}\mathbb {E} \left[X_{i}^{2}\right]+{\tfrac {1}{3}}Mt}}\right).} $$

So the inequality given by your teacher is just an application of the Bernstein inequality above with $X_i\equiv X_i - p$, $M\equiv 1$ and $t\equiv n\varepsilon$.

That being said, what is normally referred to as the Chernoff bound is at the core of the proof of Bernstein's inequality above. Indeed, the general Chernoff bound is given by :
$$\Pr\left\{\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(X_{i}-E[X_{i}]\right)\ge\varepsilon\right\}\leq
\exp\left[-\sup_{t\ge 0}\left(t\varepsilon-\psi(t)\right)\right]$$
where
$$\psi(t)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(\ln E\left[e^{tX_{i}}\right]-tE\left[X_{i}\right]\right), $$
and you can see in this proof that Bernstein's inequality is obtained by maximizing the quantity between brackets with respect to $t$.
